# Spark - searching spatial data - partition pruning

Tags: sql, apache-spark, spatial

I have a large quantity of geotagged rows - hundreds of millions - that I need query using Spark SQL doing distance calculations for all points. The SQL works ok using basic triginometry and a haversine distance function. The result set is returned WHERE latitude between +/- meters for a latitude point, and the same for longitude; ordered by distance DESC, and I do a top-n to find the closest points. So far so good. 
The data is global, so storing all points in memory is inefficient.

My questions:

1. How much benefit could I realize using partitioning pruning by partitioning the data into latitude ranges, with longitude subranges? That would reduce the search area to 1-3 latitude partitions, and a < 10 longitude subpartitions. This is a lot less data; but I dont know is the Spark SQL optimizer can prune partitions and subpartitions. I am also unclear if partition pruning on a cached RDD is particularly beneficial. There is no join involved.
2. I could partition using Parquet files, and subsequently only read in the parquet partitions needed, instead of all data. Is there any other file format that I should use that has a partitioning capability?

Answer (score 0):

You'll really only benefit from partition pruning when you do the initial read.  Spark SQL's optimizer will do some pruning if your data is already in a columnar data format (like parquet) and you're not reading all the columns, like any other SQL db would do.  If you do some filtering of the data prior to caching, you'll only be querying and persisting a smaller subset of data anyways.  The optimizer will take the queries you pass in and do the best to read the minimal amount of data from disk.

ORC files would be another file format you might want to look into.  ORC is generally smaller in size when sitting on the HDFS, but its slower when it comes to reading the data off of disk.

Finally, when caching a dataframe, spark-sql will use a columnar compression format for persisting the data, you should be able to put more in memory then you think with this.  This also allows for very efficient querying, as you don't have to read data that won't show up in your results.